# How To Consume OAuth2 Protected REST Services: Using github

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-test

I am writing java based client application which has to connect to the web application which is protected with oAuth2.

I want to use grant type as "password" which is to be authenticated with GitHub.

Here is my code.

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token");
//-- set the clients info
resourceDetails.setClientId("xxxxxxxx");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("xxxxxxx");

// set scopes
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
scopes.add("user:email");
resourceDetails.setScope(scopes);

//-- set Resource Owner info
resourceDetails.setUsername("xxxxx");
resourceDetails.setPassword("xxxxx");`
```

Comment: can you please explain the problem you are facing and the expected behaviour?

Comment: Establish application to application authentication using git oauth flow. I found the solution, Git has a personal user token which can be used instead, PAT does not require authorization flow. Here is my sample

Comment: `        SerenityRest.given()
                .spec(getBaseUrl())
                .auth().preemptive().oauth2(getPat())`

Comment: public String getPat(){
        return variables.getProperty(".test.user.pat");
    }